# Intellij Plugin Developement - Get the object while debugging

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

How do I get the object under caret, in my plugin action? The plugin is supposed to work only in Debugger context. I got the PSI file and get all the information about the class and its constituents, but I am lost on how to get the reference of the actual object. I am assuming, it is part of the Debugger context.

Note: I figured that something like this must be part of the Intellij Evaluate feature (Alt + Click on an object while in debugging context). I downloaded the source code and I found EvaulateActionHandler under debugger.actions, but I am still stuck.

Comment: What do you mean, the object under caret? what object are you looking for? The PSI element?

Comment: The PSI element provides me the details about the class. I want access to the Runtime object and its attributes. Assume I am trying to build a debugger plugin similar to "Inspect" or "Add to watchlist" or "Evaluate".